# Laravel eloquent query with sum of related table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table **users** and **posts** with columns **user_id** and **post_views**.
In **post_views** I keep information how many times post was display.

And now, in query I would like to get *user* with sum of **post_views** all his posts.

I tried do something like this:

```
User::where(['id'=>$id])->with('posts')->get();
```

And in model I defined:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post')->sum('post_views','AS','totalViews');
    }
```

But without success.

How to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a modified [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}

$user = User::withCount(['posts as post_views' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(post_views)'));
}])->find($id);
// $user->post_views
```

Comment: Works absolutely perfect.:) Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`User::withCount('posts')->find($id)`

to get the user with the id `$id` and a `posts_count` attribute in the response

I'm not fully sure what the intention of `->sum('game_plays','AS','totalVies');` is - you would need to add more context if you want this

Just something to add with regards to your shown code: No need to query by id using where + the get() at the end will make you query for a collection. If you want to get a single result use find when searching by id

Comment: Sorry, this one (->sum('game_plays','AS','totalVies');) was wrong copy and paste. Should be: ->sum('post_views','AS','totalVies'). But your code doesn't count what I want. Your code, counting number of records for users, so result it number of posts belongs to user. I need to count total sum of views from all posts belongs to user.

Answer (score 0):

As always laravel has a method for that : `withSum` (Since Laravel v8)

> Note : I know that at the time of the message was posted, the method did not exist, but since I came across this page when I was looking for the same result, I though it might be interesting to share.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

In your case it should be :

```
$user = User::withSum('posts as total_views', 'post_views')->find($id);
```

Then you can access to the result :

```
$user->total_views
```