# Laravel Eloquent - Sum multiple relation columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm not an `Eloquent` master, and I did a lot of research and couldn't reproduce what I expected.

I have the following models:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'uuid',
        'number_id'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'started_at',
        'ended_at'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;


    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'incoming_messages',
        'outgoing_messages',
        'outgoing_template_messages',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;


    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);
    }
}
```

When I search for a specific `Invoice::class`:

```php
$invoice = Invoice::number($number)
    ->latest('started_at')
    ->with(['contacts'])
    ->firstOrFail();
```

I need it to be returned that way:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "number_id": "444a13fd-9789-426e-bdfb-c3e2e83c4422",
    "incoming_messages": 10, #(sum of invoice.contacts.incoming_messages)
    "outgoing_messages": 10, #(sum of invoice.contacts.outgoing_messages)
    "outgoing_template_messages": 10, #(sum of invoice.contacts.outgoing_template_messages)
    "started_at": "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000000Z",
    "ended_at": "2020-07-31T23:59:59.000000Z"
}
```

I am currently doing this within `InvoiceResource::class`:

```php
$incoming_messages = $this->contacts->sum('incoming_messages');
$outgoing_messages = $this->contacts->sum('outgoing_messages');
$outgoing_template_messages = $this->contacts->sum('outgoing_template_messages');
```

However the data volume is very large and I would like to remove the `EagerLoading` and do everything in a single query to decrease the impact on the database.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem using just `Eloquent`?

---

### Update

A friend helped me with the query that I would like to convert to `Eloquent`:

```sql
SELECT a.number_id
, sum(incoming_messages) as 'incoming_messages' 
, sum(outgoing_messages) as 'outgoing_messages'
, sum(outgoing_template_messages) as 'outgoing_template_messages'
, a.started_at
, a.ended_at
FROM invoices a
inner join contacts b on a.id = b.invoice_id
Where number_id = '45bh1h2g14h214hg2'
Group By a.started_at , a.ended_at
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then you should not remove the `EagerLoading` as it currently thats the thing that saves you a lot of queries. I think you should have only two at the moment: one gets you the invoice and one gets you the contacts of the invoice. Doing `$this->contacts->sum('incoming_messages');` does not make additional queries.

Comment: @thefallen The problem is: At some point I can have more than 100,000 contacts per invoice. As far as I know `EagerLoading` will return to me all contacts data, and in the end I only need the sum of the specified columns. Mysql can sum this without returning all contacts, it would save me some resources...

Comment: Here is a "hack" which exploits the [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method: [laravel-eloquent-query-with-sum-of-related-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234458/laravel-eloquent-query-with-sum-of-related-table). But personally I would rather use `Invoice::hydrateRaw('<your_raw_query>', <bindings>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make the query using only eloquent. My database performance has changed dramatically as expected.

This is the query using only eloquent:

```php
$invoice = Invoice::number($number)
    ->selectRaw('invoices.uuid as uuid,
    invoices.number_id as number_id,
    count(*) as contacts,
    sum(incoming_messages) as incoming_messages,
    sum(outgoing_messages) as outgoing_messages,
    sum(outgoing_template_messages) as outgoing_template_messages,
    invoices.started_at,
    invoices.ended_at')
    ->join('contacts', 'contacts.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
    ->groupBy('invoices.id')
    ->latest('started_at')
    ->firstOrFail();
```

---

### Update

I got into a problem where my query didn't return invoices that didn't have any contacts, I had to make a small change.

The `join()` method generates an `inner join`, the `inner join` does not include rows from `table A` that have no elements in `table B`.

To overcome this situation, a `left join` must be used. However, if the `left join` has no values in `table B`, it was returning my sums as `null`.

To solve this I simply used the MySql function `ifnull()`.

This is the final query:

```php
$invoices = Invoice::number($number)
    ->selectRaw('invoices.uuid as uuid,
    invoices.number_id as number_id,
    ifnull(count(contacts.id), 0) as contacts,
    ifnull(sum(incoming_messages), 0) as incoming_messages,
    ifnull(sum(outgoing_messages), 0) as outgoing_messages,
    ifnull(sum(outgoing_template_messages), 0) as outgoing_template_messages,
    invoices.started_at,
    invoices.ended_at')
    ->leftJoin('contacts', 'contacts.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
    ->groupBy('invoices.id')
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$incoming_messages = $this->contacts()
      ->selectRaw('SUM(incoming_messages) as incoming_messages, SUM(outgoing_messages) as outgoing_messages, SUM(outgoing_template_messages) as outgoing_template_messages')
      ->get();
```

You *might* be able integrate this in your original query as follows:

```
$invoice = Invoice::number($number)
    ->latest('started_at')
    ->with(['contacts' => function ($q) {
         $q->selectRaw('SUM(incoming_messages) as incoming_messages, SUM(outgoing_messages) as outgoing_messages, SUM(outgoing_template_messages) as outgoing_template_messages');
    }])
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Then you'd access the values as `$invoice->contacts->incoming_messages` etc. To get this to work when selecting more than one invoice you may need to add `groupBy('invoice_id')` if Invoice-contacts is a 1 to many relationship (i.e. there's only one invoice for a contact) if it's many to many you might end up needing to join the pivot table.

Comment: How to put this inside the main query? `Invoice::number($number)`

Comment: Try the update. I've not tested it myself but it might work

Comment: I tried something similar before creating this topic. I tried your query and the `contacts` attribute comes like this: `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use a Mutator for this:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

```
public function incomingMessages()
{
    return $this->contacts->sum('incoming_messages');
}
```

And in your Resource you will just call:

```
$this->incomingMessages()
```