# sum of one to many relation in laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, database

I have an invoice table that has one to many relations with payment and I need to sum all columns in the payment ex.
invoice (id-method-total_price)

payments (id-invoice_id-amount)

and here is my query

```
Invoice::select('id', 'status', 'service_inv_cat_id')
    ->with(['payment' => function ($q) use ($date){
        $q->select('id','invoice_id','type', 'method', 'amount', 'responsible_worker', 'paid_date')
    ;}])
    ->orderBy('status', 'ASC');
 ->withSum('payment', 'amount')
->get
```

and what I get with (->withSum('payment', 'amount')) is the sum of payment not all the payments

for example

invoice 1: payments: 10 90
invoice 2: payments: 40 10

so when I use with sum i get only the sum of each column which is invoice 1: 100 but I need to get all sum which is 159

Comment: this should give you sum of `amount` column for all related payments, for each invoice. Isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751261/laravel-eloquent-sum-multiple-relation-columns) post will be helpful for you. You should add custom SQL, and take sum for multiple columns.

Comment: @Ksi I need to get all related payments for all invoice payments.

Comment: @ShadyHesham then instead of `withSum` use `with('payments')` only. If that's not what you want then rephrase your question so it's easier to understand

Comment: i have just done it, thank you