# Eloquent Aggregates

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi i have that query is it possible to insert additional count that counts self the Customer table rows? something like  {{count($customers)}}

Also i have join the Services table on model, how can i add SUM on specific column of services table on the query above?
for example Service->sum('price');

```
      $customers = Customer::query((['id', 'name', 'plate']))
       
      ->search($this->search,['id', 'name', 'plate'])
      ->withCount('services')     
      ->orderBy($this->sortBy,$this->sortDirection,['id', 'name', 'plate'])
      ->paginate($this->perPage,['id', 'name', 'plate']);
     
      return view('livewire.customers.show',['customers'=>$customers])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel eloquent query with sum of related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234458/laravel-eloquent-query-with-sum-of-related-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change anything. The paginator already knows the total count.

`$customers->total()` should give you the count you're looking for.

As for the sum on a related column, Laravel added somewhat recently the withAggregates functions (`withSum`, `withAvg`). You should be able to get the total price by adding

```php
->withSum('services as total_price', 'price')
```

to your query

Comment: i had something similar i think its the same,
Regarding second question do you know how  add SUM on specific column of services table on the query above? for example Service->sum('price');

Comment: You could use the `withSum()` method to get the total price.